# Highcharts Tooltip on Load/ Not Responsive

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was hoping to get some help on Highcharts/Highstock. I created a jsFiddle with my chart so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/Wolfs_Brain/qhgxd813/1/

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

I would like the Tooltip to show up initially without ruining responsiveness.

I have commented out the last two functions to point out the ones that seem to be causing the issue. If you uncomment these two:

```
function(chart){
    // Last point in graph...
    showLastPointTooltip(chart);
    chart.series[0].data[i].setState('select');
}

function showLastPointTooltip(objHighStockchart){
    //show tooltip for last point   
    var points=[];
    if(objHighStockchart)
    {
    for(var i=0;i<objHighStockchart.series.length;i++)
        points.push(objHighStockchart.series[i].points[objHighStockchart.series[i].points.length-1]);
        objHighStockchart.tooltip.refresh(points);
    }
};
```

the graph will function how i'd like but it is no longer responsive.

If you need any other information from my part please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean it's not responsive? Functions decently here.

Comment: Highcharts is supposed to be mobile friendly (Responsive no matter what the screensize is )out of the box, and it is unless I add the two functions I mentioned previously.

Comment: So general goal is print tooltip for last point, but could you elaborate what you mean by not responvie? Could you update your code which introduce that issue (with static reposinve width) and send us a mockup how it should be printed?

Comment: Here you go Sebastian. https://jsfiddle.net/Wolfs_Brain/qhgxd813/2/ I uncommented the last two functions and as you can see it is working how I'd like except for being responsive. If you resize the window you can see the chart does not change size. It should change size depending on the size of the output window.

Comment: I uncommented these lines but still seems to not print toolitp: https://jsfiddle.net/41w7krf0/. Could you update your example and introduce the problem ? Take a screenshots and elaborate how it should look like ?